# Jenkins SSH Username with Private key sent to script which calls docker container

Tags: docker, jenkins, ssh, dockerfile

Currently we have many Jenkins job which use the username and password credentials variables, which are then passed into a docker container as environment variables by a shell script. The docker container then PULLS source code from bit bucket using these credentials and performs the builds. This is working great, but now we have to switch over to use SSH Username with Key.

I've set these credentials up in Jenkins and its pulling down the source code, attempting to trigger the docker build but getting stuck here as I cant seem to send those credentials then over to the docker container.

Is anyone able to provide some guidance?

Within the Jenkins job is a shell script which basically runs the below:

```
docker run --rm \
-e JOB="build-release" \
-e LOG_FOLDER=$logDirectory \
-v $logDirectory:$logDirectory \
-e TEMP_FOLDER=$tempFolder \
-v $tempFolder:$tempFolder \
-e BRANCH_NAME=$branch \
-v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock \
dtr.com/test/checkout-build
```

There were previously bitbucket username and password variables passed above which had been removed.

The error being thrown within the docker container is:

```
'Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
Host key verification failed.'
```

I had assumed by mapping the /var/run/docker.sock, that the docker deamon would be able to communicate with the machine hosting the docker, and use its ssh keys to access bitbucket, but I guess not :(

Comment: What is the issue you are facing? Is SSH key also password protected?

Comment: Could you provide a code snippet of your workflow?

Comment: @TarunLalwani the ssh key is only username and keyfile, and the keys are also available on the Jenkins machines

Comment: @hdhruna its unfortunately not written as pipeline code, just manually setup in jenkins (I think its called a freestyle job?), Ive included some snippets of what its trying to do and also the error message from within the container.

Comment: it would be good to see the flow checkout-build. and you're indeed mounting some temp-directories to your container. I hope you've modified the base docker image `dtr.com/test/checkout-build` to include your keys for checkout. I'd suggest export the keyfile using credentialsProvider plugin in your pipeline stage to the `TEMP_FOLDER` and in the next step you can run the docker run command. Just make sure you have the base docker image changes to move the keyfile from that mounted temp folder to whereever you want and use.